# Выстроить блок в линию с переносом

Tags: css

Как сделать, чтобы все дочерние элементы `block` были бы в одну строку, а если они не помещаются по ширине, то переносились бы на следующую, но не каким-то отдельным узлом, а именно частично.

```
    <div id="block">
        <div>Текст1</div>
        <a>Текст2</a>
        <span>Текст3</span>
    </div>
```

**UPD:** В моём случае хватило `.block > div {display:inline;}`

Answer (score 1):

```css
.block {
  background: #512;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  padding: 40px;
  background: #693;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="block">
  <div class="div item">div</div>
  <a class="link item">link</a>
  <span class="span item">span</span>
  <div class="div item">div</div>
  <a class="link item">link</a>
  <span class="span item">span</span>
  <span class="span item">span</span>
  <div class="div item">div</div>
  <a class="link item">link</a>
  <span class="span item">span</span>
</div>
```